# Is anyone using node.js with an OAuth2.0 authentication system?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

Is there an OAuth2.0 library for Node.js, which is being used (or planned to be used) in a live, production system?

Comment: You could check this post with passport.js ;) http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=695

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) is generally a good bet.

Comment: A quick look through the git repo didn't show anything about OAuth2. Did I miss something?

Comment: There is very, very little documentation about how to actually do Facebook authentication via node-oauth.

Answer (score 8):

node-oauth provides some support for Oauth2.

"Also provides rudimentary OAuth2 support, tested against facebook connect and github. For more complete usage examples please take a look at connect-auth (http://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth)"  taken from https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

Comment: Also Simple OAuth2 is a good solution. It supports the Authorization code flow and the Password Credentials flow and you can easily refresh the token when it expires. It also comes out with a good documentation.

http://andreareginato.github.com/simple-oauth2/

Comment: The http://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth repository is really confusing. I still can't find a oauth2 code example.